# Pagination with rows by week

Tags: php, html, mysqli, pagination

I'm using the following code to apply a pagination to a large table in my database. It works fine however I can't figure out how to apply a `WHERE Week="?"` (52 weeks in the table) in the `SELECT Query` with the `$start $limit` variables. That way when I hit PREVIOUS or NEXT buttons it goes to the previous or next week of rows in that week.

```
<div id="content">
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
$start=0;
$limit=10;

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $start=($id-1)*$limit;
}
else{
    $id=1;
}
//Fetch from database first 10 items which is its limit. For that when
page open you can see first 10 items. 
$query=mysqli_query($dbconfig,"select * from user LIMIT $start, $limit");
?>
<ul>
<?php
//print 10 items
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<li>".$result['username']."</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
//fetch all the data from database.
$rows=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbconfig,"select * from user"));
//calculate total page number for the given table in the database 
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);
if($id>1)
{
    //Go to previous page to show previous 10 items. If its in page 1 then it is inactive
    echo "<a href='?id=".($id-1)."' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a>";
}
if($id!=$total)
{
    ////Go to previous page to show next 10 items.
    echo "<a href='?id=".($id+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a>";
}
?>
<ul class='page'>
<?php
//show all the page link with page number. When click on these numbers go     to particular page. 
        for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
        {
            if($i==$id) { echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li>"; }

            else { echo "<li><a href='?id=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
        }
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably looking for a select box for the weeks, then use that value in your where clause.

```
<select name="weeks">
    <?php 
        for( $i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++ ):
            echo '<option name="week" value="'.$i.'"></option>';
        endfor;
    ?>
</select>
```

The query:

```
$mysqli = dbConnect();
$stmt   = $mysqli->prepare( $sql );

if( !empty( $_POST['weeks'] ) ):
    $week = $_POST['week'];

    // Validate the data

    $week = trim( $week );
    $week = htmlspecialchars( $week );

    if( !ctype_digit( $week ) ):
        echo 'Week is not a valid input';
    else:
        // Prepared statement

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE week = ? LIMIT ?, ?";
        $stmt->bind_param("iii", $week, $start, $limit);

    endif;

else:
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user LIMIT ?, ?";
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $start, $limit);
endif;

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result(yourparamshere);

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Note:

Please take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Prepared statements and stored procedures are much saver and will make you a better programmer.

Comment: Why don't you look at prepared statements yourself?

Comment: Why don't you answer the question yourself? Just trying to help here.

Comment: You made this code exemplary vulnerable to SQL injection. I doubt it could be called a help.

Comment: An injection attack is what I'm worried about. I use PDO in all of my other queries however this one has me stumped. I'd have to bind each weekly variable (from the prev/next buttons) in the SELECT query somehow.

Comment: I edited my answer. Are your prev/next buttons for weeks or for pages? Or both?

Comment: To scroll from week to week. I'm staying on the same page. I'll try your answer tonight and see what I get. Hopefully it's a winner. Thanks